# Can not make python's regular expressions ignore case in unicode string

Tags: python, regex

Can not make python's regular expressions ignore case in unicode string.

```
mach = re.search(ur'(?P<mach>(?<=\s)%s(?=[\s\.]))' % u'смотреть', st, re.I | re.U)
```

Where

```
st = u" человека... Смотреть телесериал на тернет. "
```

Notice the word - `Смотреть`?

I want my regular expression to find this word as well as  this `смотреть`

So far:

```
print mach
> None
```

**PS:
Everyone can now start to minus my question. It really works now. Even from my example. However, I've spent half of the day to fix this.**

Comment: If I use `st` in defining the regex instead of u'смотреть' *and* drop `re.I`, `re.search` still returns None. I don't think case insensitivity is the problem here.

Comment: Could you try `st = u" человек..."` instead?

Comment: Can't you do a `st.lower()` before checking against the expressions?

Comment: Sorry, forget to point it out. It is unicode to.

Comment: I can not do st.lower() because I will need to replace that string wrapped with tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a string for `st`. That way it is matching the unicode regex to some byte string (depending on your encoding). Use a unicode string:

```
st = u" человека... Смотреть телесериал на тернет. "
print re.search(ur'(?P<match>(?<=\s)%s(?=[\s\.]))' % u'смотреть', st, re.I | re.U).groupdict()
#  {u'match': u'\u0421\u043c\u043e\u0442\u0440\u0435\u0442\u044c'}
```

Comment: I did what you posted. It still returns None.

Comment: But if I substitute `смотреть` to `Смотреть` in regex than it finds it.